# Howto start writing iPad applications?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, ipad

I know Objective-C from Desktop Apple Programming.

But i want to jump on the iPad bandwagon and start developing some small edutainment applets.

Is the iPad API the same as iPhone just with more power?
Do i need to join the iPhone developer program and does it still start with $100.

Is there any iPad emulator yet?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Join the Developer Program and pay the $99. You will then have access to all the tools you need to get code running on the iPhone, iPod and iPad. There is no iPad hardware yet but you can run applications in the Simulator on your Mac to start with.

Comment: you can get the sdk simulator and xcode from apple without paying the $100 you only need to pay when your ready to test on a device

Comment: Unfortunately, the 3.2 beta SDK is under NDA and requires a developer account.

Comment: @unkwntech In order to get access to the 3.2 beta SDK (which includes the iPad stuff), one needs to fork over the $99 fee.

Answer (score 5):

> Is the iPad API the same as iPhone just with more power?

I think it's basically the same thing. There may be some differences as far as laying out a UI goes, but otherwise I think they're pretty much identical. According to the [iPad SDK](http://www.apple.com/ipad/sdk/) page, you build against the iPhone SDK.

> Do i need to join the iPhone developer program and does it still start with $100.

Yes (to both queries).

> Is there any iPad emulator yet?

Yes, it is available with the SDK (similarly to the iPhone emulator that ships with the SDK).

Comment: Don't be fooled. Its not the same thing: you can treat it as the same thing if you really want, but you will be writing poor applications. There is an interesting lecture by Evan Doll on iPad programming http://deimos3.apple.com/WebObjects/Core.woa/Feed/itunes.stanford.edu.3124430053.03124430055

Comment: @Andiih, thanks for the link, the presentation is on http://www.slideshare.net/edog1203/stanford-cs193p-designing-for-ipad but I can't find the audio/video of the talk.  Evan Doll has a course called CS 193P at stanford, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xQzLHgls63E

Comment: that's probably last years cs193p not this years. goto iTunesU (in iTunes application) and look for cs193p there. You'll find the lecture easily. The iTunesURL is <a href="http://deimos3.apple.com/WebObjects/Core.woa/Feed/itunes.stanford.edu.3124430053.03124430055
">here</a> if it works.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simulator (not the same thing as an emulator - same situation as with the iPhone there).

Yes, you'll need to join the dev program - but you can sign up for free if you jsut want to download and play with the SDK and simlator.

The APIs are essentially a slight superset of the iPhone SDKs (it's the same platform, just that the iPad obviously has some hardware differences, and this has also lead to some software metaphor differences).

I can't say much more due to the NDA, but as you can get the SDK and docs yourself for free why not just go and download it now?

Comment: If you don't pay the $99 you will not have access to beta stuff like the iPad tools.

Comment: Since the iPad SDK is still beta, you have to have paid the $99 to download it. You can get the iPhone SDK for free, though, and start learning the platform with that.

Comment: Ah ok - I didn't realise that. Both my dev accounts are fully paid up so it just worked for me - thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best answer it to wait for 2-3 days, and web will be full of references on how to do that.
Till then you can read more at: 
http://www.apple.com/ipad/sdk/

Answer (score 0):

If its anything like the iPhone SDK you need an Intel Mac to use it.

I don't have an Intel Mac ... so it would just cost me too much cash to get started!

(I've been asked a few times to write iPhone apps - but they were not prepared to cover the upfront costs of buying or even just lend me either the device itself or a machine capable of running the SDK emulator for testing)