# Create an iPad application for sending the selected photo as an attachment in an email

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image, ipad, email

I need to Create an iPad application for sending the selected photo as an attachment in an email.

- The TO and CC address can be typed or must be able to select from contacts if they have email address added.

As I am a new guy in iPhone/iPad application can any one provide me a good way to do it. Any sample apps, paths to refer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Howto start writing iPad applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155190/howto-start-writing-ipad-applications)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you take a look at `MFMailComposeViewController` in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html). The examples there will help. You'll want to include the `MessageUI.framework` as well. This should get you going with mailing within an app.

For the picture side, check out `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`.